# How to apply a QGraphicsEffect to child widgets with a viewport?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm trying to apply a `QGraphicsEffect` to all the child widgets of a given widget, let's just say a `QDialog`. To do this, I set the graphics effect of the dialog, and it works as expected for everything except child widgets with a viewport (`QScrollArea`, `QAbstractItemView`, etc). These will render correctly (with the effect applied) when resizing the window frame, but on any internal updates (re-rendering a newly selected item in a `QListView`, say) it re-renders without the effect applied.

I know you can assign a `QGraphicsEffect` to the viewport of a `QAbstractScrollArea`, but this doesn't work for me since I want to be able to use the one effect across all of the child widgets (effect properties will be dynamic/animated), and you can't apply the same effect to multiple sources.

Here is an example that shows the peculiar rendering using a `QListView`:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
d.show()

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
d.setLayout(layout)

lw = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
lw.addItems(["dog", "cat", "fish", "platypus"])
layout.addWidget(lw)

btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("so fuzzy!")
layout.addWidget(btn)

ge = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()
lw.viewport().setGraphicsEffect(ge)  # assign effect to viewport
d.setGraphicsEffect(ge)  # AND to whole dialog?
ge.setBlurRadius(20)
```

and a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and you can't apply the same **[instanced]** effect to multiple sources.

In the last lines of your code, you're attempting to set the graphics effect for two widgets using the same instanced class.  Alas, you cannot!  From the Qt Documentation, [QGraphicsItem.setGraphicsEffect()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QGraphicsItem.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.setGraphicsEffect)

> If effect is the installed effect on a different item, will remove the
> effect from the item and install it on this item.

The approach to take here is to create a QGraphicsEffect instance - for each widget.  Then, for `QScrollArea, QAbstractItemView`, run their find children methods (`.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget)` ) to iterate & set their graphics effects:

```
ge = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect
d.setGraphicsEffect(ge())

lw.viewport().setGraphicsEffect(ge())

# Find List Widget's child widgets.  Assign their graphics effect.
lw_children = lw.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget)
for c in lw_children:
    c.setGraphicsEffect(ge())
```